# Can't push files to GitHub via PhpStorm [MacOs]

Tags: git, macos, github, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm trying to configure my PhpStorm to send files to GitHub, but it failed. I can push files via `Github Desctop`, but I cannot do the same via PhpStorm.

My Github account correctly connected to PhpStorm. I can do checkouts, but I cannot `commit` and `push` files

**My error:**
`Push failed: Failed with error: unable to access 'https://github.com/***/***..git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

**Tech specs:**
- Mac OS High Sierra
- PhpStorm 2018.1
- GitHub Desktop v1.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you did [register a GitHub account in PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/manage-projects-hosted-on-github.html).

If your GitHub account is using [2FA (2-factor authentication)](https://blog.github.com/2013-09-03-two-factor-authentication/), you would need to [configure an Access token first](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/).

Check also if the wrong [credentials are cached in the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/).

Finally, consider [switching to an SSH URL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-git-integration.html) if https, for some reason, does not work.

Comment: Hi, I have watched all your ways...My account is registered... I don't have 2FA... but still doesn't work. It worked for me when I was doing my project in Android Studio

Comment: @Antonio112009 Then try and swith to SSH: that might be easier.

Comment: I found error via terminal... It shows me my old account... I need to find way to change my Acc in PhpStorm

Comment: I'm reading... but all answers are about Windows and most of them are copy-paste. Now I have question how to switch account in PhpStorm for github... I still have problem

Comment: @Antonio112009 What command did you type to see your old account?

Comment: `git push`... after `git commit`. I suppose I need to use your advise with `Keychain`. I suppose Git still reading my old acc.

Comment: Again, well done! The wrong credentials must have been cached in the OSX Keychain.